# Quantile normalisation in R

Tags: r, normalization

i am trying to quantile normalize a dataset but can't seem to find the right command for it.

There was not much luck about it in python. I checked the github thingy shawnLYU but i couldn't install the Quantile_Normalize package as pip can't seem to find it. Afterwards, I decided to use R and there's a package preprocessCore but it says it doesn't work on my version of R. Also, in the documentation it doesn't say which versions does it support. And yes I have checked its is the latest version i'm using. Please help me do it.

Answer (score 0):

I checked ShawnLYU's GitHub page and you could download the script and import the function. There's no need to `pip install` it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a package called qnorm that does quantile normalization in Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import qnorm

df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': {'A': 5, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4},
                   'C2': {'A': 4, 'B': 1, 'C': 4, 'D': 2},
                   'C3': {'A': 3, 'B': 4, 'C': 6, 'D': 8}})

print(qnorm.quantile_normalize(df))


         C1        C2        C3
A  5.666667  5.166667  2.000000
B  2.000000  2.000000  3.000000
C  3.000000  5.166667  4.666667
D  4.666667  3.000000  5.666667
```

See [here](https://github.com/Maarten-vd-Sande/qnorm) for docs.

You can install it easily with pip

```
pip install qnorm
```